# Do fast charge technologies wear down the batteries quicker?

Tags: battery

There are plenty of fast charge technologies out there, [now seemingly going up to 120W](https://www.theverge.com/2019/6/20/18692589/vivo-super-flashcharge-120w-fast-charging-time), which can supposedly:

> ... capable of fully charging a 4,000mAh phone battery in just 13 minutes ...

Now I am no expert in physics or material technologies, but intuitively thinking increasing the effect (without changing the input current) could result in wearing down the batteries on the long run, assuming that the batteries burst into flames first.

I was wondering if there is any information out there available, with respect to how well the batteries hold in the long run, with these newer, high powered charging solutions.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, yes. Charging quickly means there will be more heat produced which is bad for the battery cells.

However, most batteries are equiped with controllers that make sure that the charging process runs smoothly to avoid reaching temperatures that would be detrimental to batteries.

Comment: In theory you are right, but I don't trust the manufacturers that they really keep charging in a range where it has no detrimental effect on the battery. A manufacturer is only interested minimizing the negative effects so that the battery has ~70% capacity left after 2 years. If you are planning to use your phone for more than that time I would recommend to only use fast charging when it is really necessary.

Comment: @Robert Also if the battery deteriorates quickly and is no longer if great use, the user must change it which is good for business.

Answer (score 2):

[Battery University](https://batteryuniversity.com/) is a very good site for explaining battery technologies and how batteries behave. Fast Charging does damage the battery life, but this can be mitigated somewhat - generally by not allowing deep discharge or fast charging above 80% and efficiently discipating heat.

IMHO you are absolutely right that manufacturers of cellphones design systems so batteries wear out faster. (In fact, by never charging my battery above 75% my battery is wearing at about 1/3rd the expected rate ). Of-course I needed to root my phone and find software tools to limit (and monitor) charging - The point is if manufacturers cared this could be done by a profile setting - and removable batteries -  rather then require almost unknown and hacks and expensive replacements -- but I think people would keep there phones longer so they would not upgrade as frequently.

Comment: The software I use to limit charging is "Battery Charge Limit" and I use "Accubattery" for my battery stats.

Comment: thanks for the link, interesting information...